# TCL split a string

Tags: string, variables, tcl

I am a newbie in TCL and was writing a script where i was trying to figure out a way to split a string using a certain character. For example I have a string like "name1,name2,name3" and then I want to have a for loop which will go through each of the names one at a time and run a command. Is it possible the for loop can split the string and do certain work with it or do i have to split the string (where each "," located) first then have a for loop?

I saw the range option but im never sure on how long the name might be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
set names "name1,name2,name3" 

foreach name [split $names ,] {
    puts $name
}
```

ref:
http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/split.htm
http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm

Particularly note the synopsis of `foreach`, where the 2nd arg is a *list*

> **foreach** *varname* *list* *body*

and the description of `split`:

> Returns a list ...